# How to configure route for oauth callback in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

This works perfectly fine in the `server.js`:

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    }),
    (req, res) => {}
);
```

But the following doesn't when used in `route.js`:

```
exports.googleCallback = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' });
  const handler = function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  };
  handler(req, res, next);
};
```

I have the following in `route.js`:

```
app.route(path + 'auth/google').get(auth.googleLogin);
```

What happens:
The second code directly goes to `/` path without waiting for Passport Google strategy to completely execute.

If I remove `res.redirect('/');` It does not go anywhere and keep loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked just fine:

```
exports.googleCallback = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' })(req, res, next);
};
```

Added callback method on the passport.